# Overriding jQuery styling with CSS for @media

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have some jQuery script that positions a sidebar menu to scroll down with the screen:

```
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    function fixDiv() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 365)
        { 
        $('#Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'margin-top': '20px'}); 
        }
      else
        {
        $('#Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'margin-top': '0'});
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fix5iv();
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

This works just fine on desktop, but behaves differently when zooming on tablets and mobile as the div is fixed on the screen and overlaps the content.

This is where I would like @media query to kick in and position the div differently when on a tablet or mobile device, overriding the styling applied by the jQuery script: (the @media styling is placed at the very bottom of my style sheet)

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web{
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 0px !important;
        }
}
```

However this code wont work for me :/ It seems the jQuery styling will always override any css positioning which I apply, and the div continues to scroll on any device.

Comment: I think your JS will override your css even if its !important .

Comment: Javascript adds inline styles, `!important` overrides inline styles, unless they are `!important` as well, so that's probably not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the jquery to only take effect if the screen size is as you require;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
    if ( $(window).width() > 759) {
    function fixDiv() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 365)
        { 
        $('#Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'margin-top': '20px'}); 
        }
      else
        {
        $('#Portfolio-Sidebar-Content-Web').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'margin-top': '0'});
        }
    }
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    fix5iv();
    }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. The jQuery still kicks in when viewed on a mobile device. I also tried changing the width value to > 900.

Comment: You could try replacing `if ( $(window).width() > 759) {`  with `if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 480px)').matches) {`